# What's the difference between a reversed tuple and a reversed list?

Tags: python, python-internals, reverse-iterator

Reversing a tuple and reversing a list returns objects of different type:

```
>>> reversed((1,2))
<reversed at 0x7fffe802f748>
>>> reversed([1,2])
<list_reverseiterator at 0x7fffebdd4400>
```

They have the same `dir`.  Neither type is a subclass of the other.

Why is that? What can one do that the other can't?

Comment: There seems to be no difference bar performance unless you are using an older version of python where you could call len on the listreverseiterator. http://bugs.python.org/issue3689.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Basically, a list implements the `__reversed__` method and returns an specialized object, while `tuple` falls back to the default implementation of `reversed` for any sequence:

```
>>> list.__reversed__
<method '__reversed__' of 'list' objects>
>>> tuple.__reversed__
AttributeError: type object 'tuple' has no attribute '__reversed__'
```

Now, why list does not default to the sequence `reversed` object has to be found in the source code for the list object itself - probably it enables some optimizations by accessing directly some of internal `list` attributes.

Actually looking at the C code, there is little difference, and certainly nothing that catches the eye -

- [default reversed](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/97e54e0e14017f42c421cf02d68ca626704632f0/Objects/enumobject.c#L230)
- [list reversed](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/97e54e0e14017f42c421cf02d68ca626704632f0/Objects/listobject.c#L2823)

I'd dare say the special list `__reversed__` implementation is a leftover from Python2 days where  `reversed`  would actually copy any other Python sequence to a `list` - so there would be no sense for other sequences to have special cases for it (and when they did implement the general `enumreverse` it was just good enough for tuples).

I am pretty sure that if one would simply comment out the  `__reversed__` slot on `listobject.c`,  Python and its lists would work as if nothing had happened, defaulting to the general case `reversed`.

Comment: Default reversed: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/enumobject.c#L230 list reversed: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L2823

Comment: What can one do that the other can't?

Comment: **Github pro-tip**: If you link to a line number in blob/master like that, the links rot as soon as the file is modified.  Instead, select the line(s) you want and then press the `y` key, to pin the link to a specific commit.  Then the line number will never drift away from the relevant code.  I've updated the links in your answer.

Comment: @wim Thanks. TIL about 'y'. I knew about the link rot, but always found the commits by hand.

Comment: Would there be any reason to have a different iterator because `list` is mutable perhaps?

Answer (score 5):

According to Python's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__reversed__):

> `object.__reversed__(self)`
>
> Called (if present) by the `reversed()` built-in to implement reverse
>   iteration. It should return a new iterator object that iterates over
>   all the objects in the container in reverse order.
>
> If the `__reversed__()` method is not provided, the `reversed()`
>   built-in will fall back to using the sequence protocol (`__len__()`
>   and `__getitem__()`). Objects that support the sequence protocol
>   should only provide `__reversed__()` if they can provide an
>   implementation that is more efficient than the one provided by
>   `reversed()`.

Comment: It seems odd that list would have a more efficient implementation available, but tuple doesn't.